# No implicit conversion of nil into String - ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I get the error "No implicit conversion of nil into String." and I just can't find the error.

Here are the lines that are messing with me.

```
def sumprogram
  softd = IO.readlines("softdrinks.txt").map! {|s| s.to_i}
  beers = IO.readlines("beers.txt").map! {|s| s.to_i}
  drink = IO.readlines("drinks.txt").map! {|s| s.to_i}
  softdrinks = puts softd.sum
  beers = puts beers.sum
  drink = puts drink.sum
  puts "\n\nBeverages consumed thus far "
  puts " " + softdrinks + "\t - \t " + beers + "\t - " + drink + "."
end
```

It's the last line, before the end that is the problem. The tables im trying to display are the individuals sums of different arrays.

Comment: Remove the `puts` in the assignments to `softdrinks`, `beers`, and `drink` because the call to `puts` returns `nil`.

Comment: I am an idiot... it works now. Thank you so much. I've been browsing around on stackoverflow for a couple hours, but every thread I've seen has been to complicated for me to comprehend. But yeah, thanks again

Comment: You're not an idiot you are just learning. In time, things will make sense and these types of error will happen infrequently.

Comment: When, in SO questions, you report an exception having been raised, please also report the line in which it occurred.

Answer (score 1):

`puts` returns `nil` so in your code here you are assigning `nil` to local variables `sofdrinks`, `beers` and `drink`.

Here is what you need to do:

```
def sumprogram
      softd = IO.readlines("softdrinks.txt").map! {|s| s.to_i}
      beers = IO.readlines("beers.txt").map! {|s| s.to_i}
      drink = IO.readlines("drinks.txt").map! {|s| s.to_i}
      softdrinks = softd.sum
      beers = beers.sum
      drink = drink.sum
      puts "\n\nBeverages consumed thus far "
      puts " " + softdrinks + "\t - \t " + beers + "\t - " + drink + "."
end
```